# Synchronizing SQL Server 2008 database with a proprietory non-SQL database using rowversion

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, data-synchronization

I am trying to synchronize SQL Server 2008 database with a proprietory third party database. In SQL Server database, I have a SyncId column of type timestamp / rowversion in the tables that I wish to synchronize. But the third party database does not support rowversion or timestamp columns. It only supports a few basic types like string, number, date (stores only date, no time component), boolean, decimal.

When I sync for the 1st time, I can probably store the SyncId as a string in the Third Party Database. Later on I will need to retrieve the highest available Sync Id in this third party database. How can I implement my custom comparison logic / sorting logic, so that I can get the highest Sync Id.

Further, how do I convert the SyncId string value back to native Sql Server datatype, when sending query or stored procedure parameter to SQL Server?

Any other ideas to implement a sync system to download incremental data changes from Sql Server 2008 to the third party database?

**EDIT:**
While retrieving the SyncId from the SQL Server database and converting to string, I am getting an exception. The code is:

```
            string sqlSyncId = "";
            SqlCommand selectNewAnchorCommand = new SqlCommand();
            string newAnchorVariable = "@sync_new_received_anchor";
            selectNewAnchorCommand.CommandText =
                "SELECT " + newAnchorVariable + " = min_active_rowversion() - 1";
            selectNewAnchorCommand.Parameters.Add(newAnchorVariable, SqlDbType.Timestamp);
            selectNewAnchorCommand.Parameters[newAnchorVariable].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            selectNewAnchorCommand.Connection = conn;

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                do
                {
                    sqlSyncId = reader["@sync_new_received_anchor"].ToString();
                } while (reader.Read());
            }



Stack Trace:    System.IndexOutOfRangeException: @sync_new_received_anchor
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
```

**EDIT:**
I also tried:

```
sqlSyncId = reader["@sync_new_received_anchor"].ToString();     //same error
sqlSyncId = reader[0].ToString();   //Works
```

Why I am not able to refer column by name?

The value which I am receiving is 101, but in the database table, SyncId column has a different hexadecimal value.

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: The problem is that your "@sync_new_received_anchor" index doesn't exist, that is why the IndexOutOfBounds exception is thrown.